# A converging sum of divergent terms

Tags: calculus

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \text{Sin}(1) \\
 2 \text{Sin}(1)-\frac{\text{Sin}(2)}{2} \\
 3 \text{Sin}(1)-\frac{3 \text{Sin}(2)}{2}+\frac{\text{Sin}(3)}{3} \\
 4 \text{Sin}(1)-3 \text{Sin}(2)+\frac{4 \text{Sin}(3)}{3}-\frac{\text{Sin}(4)}{4} \\
 5 \text{Sin}(1)-5 \text{Sin}(2)+\frac{10 \text{Sin}(3)}{3}-\frac{5 \text{Sin}(4)}{4}+\frac{\text{Sin}(5)}{5} \\
 6 \text{Sin}(1)-\frac{15 \text{Sin}(2)}{2}+\frac{20 \text{Sin}(3)}{3}-\frac{15 \text{Sin}(4)}{4}+\frac{6 \text{Sin}(5)}{5}-\frac{\text{Sin}(6)}{6}
\end{array}
\right) $$

The above is an infinite triangle, where every line is approximately equal to 1, getting closer as you move down on the triangle. Also...

$$\lim_{m\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{n=1}^m \frac{(-1)^n \sin (n) \binom{m}{n}}{n}\right)=-1$$

How does one prove this simple result? Every term in the series is divergent when it is summed... Is there a name given to this and where can I find more information?

Comment: Are you using degrees or radians ?

Comment: Like 1,2,3,Pi,4,5,6...

Comment: Haha, so your point is that I am stupid and I dont know what I am saying. Such a comment is happily returned to its rightful owner.

Comment: @guest : You are looking for an analytical extension (like $1+2+3+4+5+...=-\frac{1}{12}$). Perhaps you will find a solution, if you are looking for, how to create an analytical extension for a  special function.

Comment: Yeah zeta function regularization. You learn that at school... Im not really looking for that. I look for a reference, or some source as to where this could have been mentioned before.

Comment: It is cool to know about degrees radians and -1/12, but apart from the jargon, can you contribute anything of substance to help me here?

Comment: I do not have the feeling that anyone suggested you could be stupid. Concerning my comment, I wanted to clarify what was the problem.

Comment: I am sorry then.

Comment: Looking for a similar sum I only find $\sum\limits_{n=1}^m (-1)^n \binom{m}{n}=-1$ (independent of $m$). That's all.

Comment: @user90369 Thanks. This is the only one you can find a quick reference for, that is what I understand.

Comment: Since $\sin(n)=\text{Im}(e^{in})$, it is enough to compute or approximate

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{(-1)^n e^{in}}{n}\binom{m}{n} = \left.\sum_{n=1}^{m}\binom{m}{n}\frac{x^n}{n}\right|_{x=-e^i}=\int_{0}^{-e^i}\frac{(1+x)^m-1}{x}\,dx $$

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I would appreciate the steps if not too time consuming.